# Как действуют восьмеричные и шестнадцатеричные основания в Java?

Tags: java, переменные, int

Может ли кто-нибудь мне объяснить, как именно действуют восьмеричные и шестнадцатеричные основания? Приведу пример.
Ввожу **int x = 077;** (восьмеричное основание).
Нажав на команду run, получаем результат 63. Вопрос — как и что происходит, чтобы **077 превратилось в 63** после компиляции?
Если надо, вот ещё один пример.
**int y = 0x1000** (шестнадцатеричное основание)
После компиляции результат равен 4096. Java я начал изучать не так давно, поэтому, прошу прощения, если вопрос вам покажется абсурдным или глупым.

Comment: java тут не при чем, это основы информатики - представление чисел в разных [системах счисления](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Ничего не происходит. 077 это то же самое, что 63, а 0х1000 то же самое, что 4096.

Comment: А самое интересное то что оно хранения вовсе по другому

Comment: Перед компиляцией Java "заменяет" эти числа на десятичные (`077` превращается в `63`, `0x1000` в `4096` и так далее). Всё это было создано для удобства программистов, на результат компиляции это не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

Если в двух программах единственное различие в исходном тексте в строках:

```
int x = 077;
```

и

```
int x = 63;
```

то в скомпилированном виде они будут абсолютно идентичны.

Работает это так. Компилятор во время компиляции, когда встречает целочисленную константу , которая начинается с нуля, то интерпретирует ее как восьмеричное число. Если упростить, то компилятор константу сразу преобразует в 63.

Answer (score 0):

Не мучайте себя такими вопросами. Абсолютно все хранится в двоичной системе. А что означает та или иная последовательность это мы вносим в это смысл. К примеру 00111111 может означать и 077 и 63 и вообще что угодно. Для вас важно понять что есть хранение и есть представление его. Так вот 077 и 63 и даже '?' это представление последовательности битов 00111111